# How can I swap latitude and longitude in in a long php string for use in leaflet polyline?

Tags: php, leaflet

I get a json response with a string of latitude and longitude in the following format:

```
 [39.608379, -106.450714],[39.608311,-106.450348],[39.608292,-106.450005],[39.608288,-106.449722]
```

My problem is that leaflet needs the the latitude and longitude to be reversed. I can't control the json data only manipulate the data in php or the leaflet javascript.

Anyone have a good way to swap the values? Note the strings are usually much long than this and vary.

Comment: A combination of `json_decode` and a loop?

Comment: What does the javascript code look like? It might be easy to swap the values there.

Comment: The javascript code is minimized. I did fine the function called t.polyline with two variables in it and tried swapping them but it broke the script.

Comment: For anyone interested in the js. https://leafletjs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple foreach will do this quite simply

```
$js = '[[39.608379, -106.450714],[39.608311,-106.450348],[39.608292,-106.450005],[39.608288,-106.449722]]';
$ja = json_decode($js);

$new_arr = [];
foreach ($ja as $j){
    $new_arr[] = [$j[1], $j[0]];
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => -106.450714
            [1] => 39.608379
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -106.450348
            [1] => 39.608311
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => -106.450005
            [1] => 39.608292
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => -106.449722
            [1] => 39.608288
        )

)
```

Comment: I had to modify it slightly for my usage but it does the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Not surprising, you didnt tell us much about your actual code :)

Comment: Well now that I implemented it with live data it isn't working. When I parse my json content I do a json_decode() and save my polyline string in a var. It comes in a little messy so I clean it up with a few lines of php to get it to the above string. I echo the var all is good. My problem now is if I json_decode again it is an empty variable.

Comment: Got it! Using the general idea you had but changing my string to use explode instead of json_decode. I don't know why I was having such a brain fart on this. Too many late nights I suppose.  Thanks for your help @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

In php

```
$json = '[[39.608379, -106.450714],[39.608311,-106.450348], [9.608292,-106.450005], [39.608288,-106.449722]]';

$json = json_decode($json, true);

$reversed = [];

foreach ($json as $el){
    $reversed[] = [$el[1], $el[0]];
}
```

You can `json_encode` it back if you want to.

With js(one of many ways):

```
var json = [[39.608379, -106.450714],[39.608311,-106.450348], 
[39.608292,-106.450005], [39.608288,-106.449722]];

var reversed = [];

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
    reversed.push([json[i][1], json[i][0]]);
}
```